# XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\r\n<!--'

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests

I currently am using python to interpret and add to data stored in xlsx files.  I am attempting to store the data in SharePoint, but am unable to use the information.  When I run the following request, I get `Out[6]: <Response [200]>`, so I know it responded to the request.

```
import requests
import json
from json import loads
import pandas as pd
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
requests.get('OneDrive file address',auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(),headers=headers)
```

However, I have tried multiple methods to put this data in a Pandas data frame, and every time have face difficulty.  When I attempted to convert to JSON, I would get the same error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)`.  Most of the solutions I found were for line 1 column 1 (char 0) and did not work for mine.  This is one of the methods I tried to convert.

```
import requests
import json
from json import loads
import pandas as pd
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
tern=requests.get('One Drive Address',auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(),headers=headers)
tern_dict=tern.json()
db=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tern_dict)
print(db)
```

The other main error I've been getting is when I tried to directly treat the file like an excel file: `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\r\n<!--'`
This would be done by using something similar to

```
import requests
import json
from json import loads
import pandas as pd
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
tern=requests.get('One Drive Address',auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(),headers=headers)
df=pd.read_excel(tern)
```

I tried to run `df=pd.read_html(tern)` instead, but the error is `ValueError: No tables found`.

How do I make this function so that I can work with the data?  In my initial version, I simply used `open()` on a local file and ran a `for` loop over each row of data, so I want to be able to do this with online file, so that multiple users are accessing the same information source.  I am sorry if any of this is unclear, I am still fairly new to programming this in-depth.

Comment: Can you write `tern.content` out to a file then open that in notepad or your favorite text editor? I suspect that you're getting either an HTML file or an XML file. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: It may be that you need to specify the header "Accept" to be "application/json". The server may be responding with html or something, which won't behave properly if you use json.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Is it the portion after `"Content-Type" `, so text/html? If I use 'tern.content', the beginning looks like: `b'\r\n\r\n<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Redirecting</title>\r\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\r\n`

Comment: @PirateNinjas Would that be adding another key called "Accept"?  I used `headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36","Accept":"application/json"}` and I still had the same error as before.

Comment: So you're getting an HTML file back from your `get` call. Try as @PirateNinjas said and add an Accept header to your get call. If that does not work, you can inspect the said HTML file to check if it even has the table or tables you need.

Comment: Yeah you'd want to add it

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It is a blank page when I copy and run the content in an html file, so I don't know if it is pulling any information.  I did not get an error when converting to json, but I also was unable to load this json data into a `DataFrame` using `df=pd.read_tern` since it is not a file.

Comment: What does  "run the content in an html file" mean? What does the file look like when opened in a text editor?

Comment: I did not think this code directly produces an html file, so I copied the output of `tern.content` into a text editor.  I chose the option to run the file in my default browser, and all that opened was a blank page.